# Dynamically creating chart in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-charts

I'm looking for a way of automatically generating a graph based on a constantly expanding dataset.

The number of columns is constantly expanding (a program create a new column with new datasets for each day).

I want to generate a graph based on the sum of each column. I can generate a sum using:

```
=SUM(index(SPLIT(filter(Date_Log!F2:F, len(Date_Log!F2:F)), ":"), 0, 1))
```

but the generating a graph part based on X number of columns is unknown.
It could probably be achieved by "automatically" copying the formula for calculating sum to the top of each column. But the "Automatically" part for each new column generated is also unknown.

[image: dataset]

Comment: I want a line graph based on the sum of every column (number of columns is NOT fixed).

Comment: And providing a copy of my spreadsheet is a big no no as it contains quite sensitive information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can use **`SPARKLINE()`** and do not include ending column (**`A9:9`**):

**`=SPARKLINE(A9:9, {"CHARTTYPE","LINE";"COLOR","GREEN";"LINEWIDTH",4})`**

[image: 1]

---

- if you want to use a chart then you will need to add some unreasonable amount of columns first and then construct your chart (like for example: **`A9:GG9`**)

[image: 2]